# Average Timestamp oracle with milliseconds

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp

Hello everyOne I need to get the AVERAGE of difference of two dates (timestamp)

I tried this

```
select AVG((sva.endTime - sva.startTime)) as seconds from SVATable sva;
```

but I got an error

```
93/5000
ORA-00932: Inconsistent data types; expected: NUMBER; got: INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `EXTRACT` to get `AVG` seconds.

```
SELECT AVG (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM (sva.endTime - sva.startTime)))
          AS avg_seconds
  FROM SVATable sva;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an insidious problem in Oracle.  Your calculation would work with the `date` data type, but it does not work with `timestamps`.

One solution is to extract the days, hours, minutes, and seconds from the interval.  Another is to use date arithmetic.  You can get fractions of a day by using:

```
select (date '2000-01-01' + (sva.endTime - sva.startTime)) - date '2000-01-01'
```

You can use the average and convert to seconds:

```
select avg( (date '2000-01-01' + (sva.endTime - sva.startTime)) - date '2000-01-01') * (60*60*24)
```